# margin bottom on grid item of table does not apply

Tags: css, firefox, css-grid

```html
<body>
  <table></table>
  <p></p>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr);
}
table, p {
  grid-column: 6 / span 14;
}
table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

[image: table’s margin bottom is not effective]

As you can see the following `p` after `table` not being pushed down.

Only happened on Firefox 71. Works fine on Chrome 78, Safari 13.0.3.

Comment: You have to use `*:after,*:before{box-sizing: border-box;}`

Answer (score 1):

Use a different tag than `<table></table>` for css-grid. Below, I used a custom tag. The reason is that the table element is heavily riddled with user-agent-defined styles and display code meant for showing tabular data. This is fighting with any attempt in changing its display type.

HTML

```
<body>
  <table-tag></table-tag>
  <p></p>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr);
}
table-tag, p {
  grid-column: 6 / span 14;
}
table-tag {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```